# Simple SOAP xml with Builder gem

Tags: ruby, xml, soap

Can you help me to build the following XML using Builder gem

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Service>
            <Source ID="1" Name="A"></Source>
        </Service>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So far I ended up with this

```
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
builder.instruct!(:xml, :encoding => "UTF-8")
builder.service { |p| p.source }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I came up with the following

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new 
xml.instruct!(:xml, :encoding => "UTF-8")

xml.soapenv(:Envelope, {"xmlns:soapenv" => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" }) do
    xml.soapenv :Header
    xml.soapenv :Body do
        xml.Service do
            xml.Source('ID' => '1', 'Name' => 'A')
        end
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use Builder gem for it? I would suggest using some other gem like Handsoap.

Comment: Thanks for advise, but it's something I have to live with:) My customer have Builder integrated and it's essential to use it.

Comment: The Builder gem is just to build XML Markup. For making the request to your service, you would need to make a POST request.  Look up the libraries for making POST requests in Ruby.

Comment: thanks. I understand that. For the moment I just looking for some valid examples of using Builder.

Comment: Did you check this link? http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/01/04/creating-xml-with-ruby-and-builder.html

Comment: yeah, saw this. Right now I'm trying to add <soapenv:Envelope> tag.